# Vue error: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or inside a block

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm running a **Vue** script with a text box and submit button, I'm calling an api to POST what I write in the textbox to the api and to return information back from the API, I'm getting this error mentioned in the title eventhough I've written the Javascript functions in vue as it should be?

With the script I'm first setting up a new XMLHttpRequest, initiating the header and api key for both GET and POST methods. I've then created 2 functions to get the data from the textbox and send them to the API, then making another button with the other function to send back the data.

I went through this approach because I kept getting a CORS issue and the API needed me to declare an access control origin header, is there anything I've done wrong with this code? Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'ProperForm'
}
    methods: {
        StartClient: function () {
            this.get = function(Url, Callback){
            var aHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            aHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (aHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && aHttpRequest.status == 200)
                Callback(aHttpRequest.responseText);
            }

            aHttpRequest.open("GET", Url, true);
            aHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Api-Key", "eVnbxBPfn01kuoJIdfgi46TiYNv8AIip1r3WbjsX");
            aHttpRequest.send(null);
        }
        this.post = function(Url, message, Callback) {
            var aHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            aHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (aHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && aHttpRequest.status == 200)
                Callback(aHttpRequest.responseText);
            }

            aHttpRequest.open("POST", Url, true);
            aHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "eVnbxBPfn01kuoJIdfgi46TiYNv8AIip1r3WbjsX");
            aHttpRequest.send(message);
            }
        }
    var client = new StartClient();

    submitData: function () {
        document.getElementById('inputBox').disabled = true;
        var targetInputButton = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
        var message = '{"targetInputButton":"' + targetInputButton + '"}';
        client.post('https://le75bkfcmg.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/start-trace', message, function(response) {
        document.getElementById('jobId').innerHTML = response;
    });
    }

    sendBackData: function () {
        var jobId = document.getElementById("jobId").innerHTML;
        var message = '{"jobId":"' + jobId + '"}';
        client.post('https://le75bkfcmg.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/check-trace', message, function(response) {
        document.getElementById('report').innerHTML = response;
    });
    }
}

</script>
```

**New way I wrote var client:**

```
StartClient: function () {
    var client 
},
```

Comment: Your `methods` don't seem to be inside the component definition. The `}` on the preceding line should be moved to the end.

Comment: Thank you but now it's saying 'client' is not defined. I rewrote the var client function in the forum but still isn't working. Am I doing something wrong here too?

Comment: @TaranBasi If that fixed the problem, please don't turn this question into a chameleon by asking a string of successive questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need put your methods object inside export and split the methods to comma

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'name',
    methods:{
        foo(){
        },
        bar(){
        }
    }
}
```

UPD: `var client = new StartClient();` 
defined outside the method

Comment: It's now inside export as skirtle mentioned, but now I'm getting a 'client is not defined' error. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I've now added 'var client = new StartClient();' but it's causing the vue site to render a blank white page, with the error 'StartClient is not defined'